# Calculate the order of permutation of cycle compositions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, permutation-cycles

What is the order of permutation in $S_6$ of: $(1 2) \circ (152) \circ (1634) \circ(125)$

Comment: I think after cycle decomposition it goes to $(12)\circ(3456)$ which would make the order $lcm(2,4)=4$ but I'm not sure if I maybe am missing something?

Comment: Are you sure of $(1 \ 5 \ 1)$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Oops sorry fixed it up! But I got the answer resolved. Thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decomposition is not  correct. You should obtain $$(1\,2)(1\,5)(1\,6\,3\,4)(1\,2\,5)=(3\,4\,5\,6),$$ so the order is the length ($4$) of this cycle.

**Edit**: with the last modification of the permutation, we have
$$(1\,2)(1\,5\,2)(1\,6\,3\,4)(1\,2\,5)=(1\,2)(3\,4\,5\,6)$$
so its order of this product is the l.c.m. of the lengths of the disjoint factors, which is again $4$.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I noticed it was incorrect and fixed it. Should be right now and thanks for your help!

Comment: B. t.w., don't denote $(1\,5\,1)$ the transposition $(1\,5)$ (unless it's really a $3$-cycle that you mistyped?).

Comment: yeah sorry someone else pointed that out and it was a typo!

Comment: Indeed it seems that there was a typo in the question which requires an answer update.